# Type issue in for...in in TS [ts(7053)]

Tags: typescript

Let's take this simple code:

```
let obj = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:3
}
for (let i in obj) {
  console.log(obj[i]);
}
```

And we get an error on `obj[i]`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' 
can't be used to index type '{ a: number; b: number; c: number; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found 
on type '{ a: number; b: number; c: number; }'. ts(7053)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: See [this comment in Github?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500#issuecomment-388883320)

Comment: @jcalz but `var i: keyof obj` will kill the purpose of `let i` inside of for...in — scope of i inside each iteration in the loop, won't it?

Comment: True... I guess you could do a type assertion then as in `for (let _i in obj) { const i = _i as keyof typeof obj; console.log(obj[i]); }`.  It's just as unsafe as any other method, given the lack of [exact types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).

Comment: And [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208) explains the thinking behind this.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function foo(abc: ABC) {
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(abc)) {
    k  // Type is string
    v  // Type is any
  }
}
```

The full post of the answer is here:

https://effectivetypescript.com/2020/05/26/iterate-objects/